# Background overlapping issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a questionnaire that asks 10 questions and keeps a score, called `total`. I want so that if the `total < 10`, the screen turns **red**, however I had to remove the wallpaper that was there previously:

```
/*body{
        background-image: url("twins.jpg");

    }*/  <-- which is now a comment
```

So that this code would work:

```
if (total < 10){ 
    alert("...RED SCREEN OF DEATH!");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
}
```

So now, when a user scores lower than 10, the screen turns red successfully, however that's now just half of the issue solved.

My next issue is that I want `twins.jpg` to be my background **before** the screen turns red, meaning I have `twins.jpg` as my wallpaper, then when `total < 10`, screen turns red.

My question is, **what is the correct way to do this so that I can still see my background change red when `total < 10` ?** When I use this:

```
body{
        background-image: url("twins.jpg");
    }
```

It changes the background to `twins.jpg`, but overlaps the **red** when it changes colour, therefore I cannot see it.

Comment: What if you put your background in your CSS by changing `background-image` by `background` like this `body{
        background: url("twins.jpg");
    }` ?

Comment: Just tried that, unfortunately doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this would probably be that you create a `<div id="redbg"></div>` around your content which is the same size than your `<body>` element (by adding a height and width of 100%).

You then add the background color to the new div:

```
if (total < 10){ 
    document.getElementById('redbg').style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
}
```

As soon as you want to remove the background color, you could do it by making it transparent:

```
document.getElementById('redbg').style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS,  properties like background and its properties like it do not override each other. If you set the image, then color, they will not over one each other.

To solve you problem, instead of using "background-image" and "background-color", change them both to just "background" as this will override the other choice.

Let me know if this solves your problem! (COMMENT)

Bryce